# module importing error exclusively when running a file

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to import and use matplotlib.pyplot in a script and I'm getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 36, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 40, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._subplots import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 22, in <module>
    import matplotlib.dates as _  # <-registers a date unit converter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 126, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import (rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 13, in <module>
    from fractions import gcd
ImportError: cannot import name 'gcd'
```

The weird part is that I can import it just fine if I restart the Python shell and import it directly, but as soon as I try to run my script, even if I run the script and then import it after running the script to generate data, I get the error. The import line, if it matters, is always the same:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

My script is being run from a folder on my desktop, and I installed matplotlib in terminal with pip3.

Comment: Did you create a file named `fractions.py` somewhere?

Comment: fractions.py is the script I'm trying to run that's in the folder on my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file called `fractions.py` is shadowing the builtin module of the same name, causing problems when other libraries try to use that library.  Name your file something else.

Comment: @PacoPoler: There may be a file called `fractions.pyc` near your `fractions.py` that you have to remove as well.

Comment: Since you are running on 3.4, your `fractions.pyc` file will be in directory  `__pycache__`.